# 2nd button will not work with event handler in Xamarin c# android app

Tags: c#, android, button, event-handling

MainActivity.cs

```
namespace testApp
{
    [Activity (Label = "DHS HotKeys", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {


    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button1 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button1);
        Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

        button.Click += delegate {
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("https://www.fridayparentportal.com/delran/");
            var intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView, uri); 
            StartActivity (intent);     
            };



        button1.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            var uri2 = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("http://dhs.delranschools.org/students/lunch_menu/");
            var intent2 = new Intent (Intent.ActionView, uri2); 
            StartActivity (intent2);     
        };


    }
}
```

}

Inside the resource designer:

```
public partial class Id
    {

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f050001
        public const int button1 = 2131034113;

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f050000
        public const int myButton = 2131034112;
```

The 2nd button is set exactly like the first, but it does nothing when clicked, while the first one opens the webpage.  The ID for 2nd button is `@+id/button1`

Thank you

Comment: onClick method of 2nd button is executing ?

Comment: I realized what you mean after i typed that and I added a breakpoint on the button1 click.  The problem ended up being that I was building a release everytime, instead of debug mode. sorry i'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

write each button closer to their eventhandler, like this :

```
Button btn1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
btn.Click += (object se,EventArgs e)
{

}
```